# Raspberry or clone with 2x sata port

Tags: raspberry-pi, sata, raid

I'd like to create my custom NAS box built on raspberry or clone. I need recommendation for an arm/atom/else board approx the size of raspb that has 2x sata ports that would enable software raid1 case for me. Not looking for usb 3.0 solutions

Comment: I'd like to create my custom NAS box built on raspberry or clone. I need recommendation for an arm/atom/else board approx the size of raspb that has 2x sata ports that would enable softwate raid1 case for me. Not looking for usb 3.0 solutions